# How to mount LED power supply

Tags: electrical, led

I am looking to install some LED strips in my closet to light it up. Since it is full of shelving, I figured I would run it up, across, and down the door frame (roughly) so the shelf contents could be seen. I am based in the northeastern USA.

I purchased these strips: [LightingWill SMD2835](http://www.lightingwill.com/led-strips/flexible-led-strips/cri-90-led-flexible-strips/dc12v-5meter-16-4ft-smd2835-300leds-roll-high-color-rendering-index-cri90-flexible-led-strips-60leds-m-12w-per-meter-ribbon-lamp-8mm-wide-white-pcb.html)

I've been looking for power supplies and I see the many varieties available, from simple plug-in AC adapters to [sealed water-resistant bars](http://www.lightingwill.com/led-strips/led-adapter-power-supply/ul-approved-power-supply/meanwell-ul-cul-certificated-lpv-series-ip67-waterproof-power-supply-110-220v-ac-to-12v-24v-dc.html) to [boxes with vent holes](http://www.lightingwill.com/led-strips/led-adapter-power-supply/ul-approved-power-supply/meanwell-ul-certificated-nes-series-switching-power-supply-85-264v-ac-to-12v-24v-48v-5v-dc.html) (and a fan, even).

It seems the latter two options generally come with bare wire only (yes, I understand that you can simply add a plug); my question is:

What are the requirements for mounting these power supplies? I highly doubt that a vented supply, with terminal leads visible can just be mounted in the open against a wall. Similarly, even with the IP rated bars that are bare wire, how do you solve the house power line connection issue?

Do you place the power supplies in some kind of electrically approved box? Do the bare wires make a connection in a junction box and then comes out through some cover plate? Or something else entirely? Curious what is out there.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to wire the LED strips together?

Comment: The strip came with two leads coming out the end, with a female terminal screw connector if needed. For adding additional strips, i was thinking of some solderless clamp style connectors.

Comment: I meant "what kind of wire are you going to use?"

Comment: I was going to have an electrician wire me an outlet, but if direct wire, then simply romex?

Comment: I'm talking about the DC side here

Comment: that i don't know... whatever will meet the electrical requirements? what do you suggest

Comment: NM works provided it's not subject to physical damage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52421/discussion-between-achao-and-threephaseeel).

Answer (score 1):

For simplistic sake. I would just use a plug in wall wart. You can plug that into a switched outlet, or a wireless switched outlet. Cheaper and less hassle if there is an outlet near your termination point.

Comment: That was certainly my original plan, but finding it slightly more difficult to find a wall wart with enough juice... though i guess two wall warts splitting the lighting in half works too

Comment: Buy one of the suggested wall plugs they have listed. Easier than trying to locate something that "may" work. I like to tinker with stuff by buying used power transformers at thrift shops.